# Inserting Img tag inside div with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have multiple tags inside a div using innerHTML.
Here's an example to better explain my issue.

```
var y = "jack.jpg";
var x = "Jack";
var f = "Hello world!";

document.getElementById("maindDiv").innerHTML += "<div class = 'result'>" + ": " + "<img src="y"/>" + ": " + x + ": " + f + "</div>" ;
```

As you can see I have too many apostrophes and I don't know how to use them so to have a variable in the src instead of a string. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the quotes

```
document.getElementById("maindDiv").innerHTML += "<div class = 'result'>" + ": " + "<img src='"+y+"'/>" + ": " + x + ": " + f + "</div>" ;
```

```js
  var y = "jack.jpg";
  var x = "Jack";
  var f = "Hello world!";

  document.getElementById("maindDiv").innerHTML += "<div class = 'result'>" + ": " + "<img src='"+y+"'/>" + ": " + x + ": " + f + "</div>" ;
```

```html
<div id="maindDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Template strings:

```
var y = 'jack.jpg';
var x = 'Jack';
var f = 'Hello world!';

document.getElementById("maindDiv").innerHTML += `<div class='result'> + : + <img src=${y}/> + : + ${x} + : ${f} + </div>`;
```

But notice:

1) Those variables are strings (y, x, f) and you forgot the quotation marks;

2) You can't use the quotation marks when you are using the variable, you must use in the creation time.

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamic variables to change image by just changing y:

You may optionally put them in for loop and iterate over an array to change the value of y:

```
var y = "jack.jpg";
var tagMaker = "<img src=\'./" + y + "\'>";
```

now use this:

```
document.getElementById("maindDiv").innerHTML += tagMaker
```

Assumptions: your image resides beside html file.